# Is there a simple way in python to find all ways to pick consecutive numbers?

Tags: python, list

Sorry about the confusingly worded title, I'm fairly new to python development and I'm not sure how to approach the following problem.

I'm trying to solve an allocation style problem which I have boiled down to the following.

Take the following example of a nested list:

```
[[0, 3], [0, 1, 2], [3], [4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

I need to find **all** ways to select one item from each sublist such that all integers 0 to 5 are selected.

In this case one way of doing so is:

- 0 -> 0
- 1 -> 2
- 2 -> 3
- 3 -> 4
- 4 -> 1
- 5 -> 5

Another way would be

- 0 -> 0
- 1 -> 2
- 2 -> 3
- 3 -> 4
- 4 -> 5
- 5 -> 1

I would also need this to be generalisable to longer lists with more numbers.

Comment: Have you already had a look at the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) `itertools.combination`? It says `r-length tuples, in sorted order, no repeated elements`

Comment: Hello! If you had to take a shot at it, what would you try? This is as much a math problem as it is a programming problem, so you first need to figure out exactly what you want to achieve. (Also, how efficient must it be? That is typically a concern with problems like these.)

Comment: @Albo Thanks, itertools turned out to have the exact functions to allow me to solve this problem easily

Comment: @TheFireballX7 Glad to hear that, I will provide and answer and be happy if you mark it as correct

Comment: @TheFireballX7 could you please mark the answer as correct, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below. ( Note that I have slightly modified the input list such that all the numbers from 0 through 5 is selected)

```
nested_list = [[0, 3], [0, 1, 2], [3], [4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [5, 9, 10]]
iter_obj = iter(nested_list)

for i, l in enumerate(iter_obj):
    is_found = False
    while not is_found:
        if i in l:
            print(f'selected {i} from list {l}')
            is_found = True
        else:
            print(f'ignoring list {l} as it does not contain {i}')
            l = next(iter_obj)
```

**Result**

```
selected 0 from list [0, 3]
selected 1 from list [0, 1, 2]
ignoring list [3] as it does not contain 2
ignoring list [4] as it does not contain 2
selected 2 from list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
selected 3 from list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
selected 4 from list [3, 4, 5]
selected 5 from list [5, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

This script prints every combination that satisfies the criteria. The values in input list must be in range `<0, lenght(input list)>`:

```
lst = [[0, 3], [0, 1, 2], [3], [4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

def find_combination(lst, idxs=[]):
    s = []
    for i, idx in enumerate(idxs):
        if 0 <= lst[i][idx] <= len(lst):
            s.append(lst[i][idx])

    if len(s) == len(lst) and len(set(s)) == len(lst):
        yield s

    for i, idx in enumerate(lst):
        if len(idxs) == i:
            for ii in range(len(lst[i])):
                yield from find_combination(lst, idxs + [ii])

for c in find_combination(lst):
    print(c)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5]
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2]
[0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5]
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

With the python builtin [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module you can easily accomplish a different kind of combinatorics fast and memory efficient like:

- cartesian product `product('ABCD', repeat=2) -> AA AB AC AD BA BB BC BD CA CB CC CD DA DB DC DD`
- permutation `permutations('ABCD', 2) -> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC`
- combination `combinations('ABCD', 2) -> AB AC AD BC BD CD`
- combination with replacement `combinations_with_replacement('ABCD', 2) -> AA AB AC AD BB BC BD CC CD DD`

and even more, like "infinite iterators" and "iterators terminating on the shortest input sequence".